# TWA Issue ~“Please install Chrome Stable 72 or later” for Android 11 Version

Tags: google-chrome, trusted-web-activity

For Android Version, less than 11 My app is working fine. But for the versions of Android 11, it shows a message ***" Please install Chrome Stable 72 or later"*** when I try to open the app.

Answer (score 0):

Change dependency from

```
implementation 'com.github.GoogleChrome:custom-tabs-client:a0f7418972'
```

to

```
  implementation 'com.google.androidbrowserhelper:androidbrowserhelper:2.2.0'
```

Also make sure Launcher activity in manifest imported from  androidbrowserhelper

```
com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.LauncherActivity
```

More migration details you can found [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/trusted-web-activity/android-browser-helper-migration/)

Answer (score -1):

Trusted Web Activity was introduced in Chrome version 72. The issue there is not related to the Android version, but that the version of Chrome installed on the devices showing this message is earlier than 72.

installing the latest version of [Chrome](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome) from Google Play should solve the issue.

Comment: This doesn't look like it. I have Chrome 101 and I am still getting that message.